# Can you yield return into an IList<T>?

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, yield-return

In my service layer for my MVC application I am attempting to convert the linq to sql entity results into my business model entities.  I am currently attempting the following code:

```
    public IList<Project> GetAllProjects()
    {
        var results = from p in _context.Repository<DBMappings.project>()
                      select p;

        foreach (DBMappings.project prj in results.ToList<DBMappings.project>())
            yield return CreateProjectEntityFromDBProject(prj);

    }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work and the only thing I can guess is that yield only works with IEnumerable.  Is there any other solution besides creating a new list, adding items in the foreach loop and returning the list?  I need to use an IList because methods that use the returned list need to be able to do List Methods such as .Sort().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to `.Sort()` you should definitely create a list in your method. using yield saves you some memory - because results are not stored as a single object. This is useful when you just want to walk over results. but if you want to Sort something you need it in memory as a single piece.

Comment: let me give you common advise on yield. Use it when you definitely know that it is useful for current task. If you doubt don't use it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Section 8.14 of the C# specification (emphasis mine):

> The yield statement is used in an
>   iterator block (§8.2) to yield a value
>   to the **enumerator object** (§10.14.4) or
>   enumerable object (§10.14.5) of an
>   iterator or to signal the end of the
>   iteration.

IList implements IEnumerable, but it does not implement IEnumerator.

Comment: Ah that explains part of my confusion.  I didn't realize there was an IEnumerator, I thought it was just IEnumable

Answer (score 2):

You can't "lazy return" a list, but it seems like you could get what you want with:

```
return results.Select(prj=>CreateProjectEntityFromDBProject(prj)).ToList();
```

or just

```
var results = from p in _context.Repository<DBMappings.project>()
                  select CreateProjectEntityFromDBProject(p);
return results.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks to how different Linq looks from normal C#, it's easy to forget that it's still C# in there...

Answer (score 1):

`IList<T>` describes functionality that is incompatible with `IEnumerable<T>`, at least as far as lazy loading goes.

Being able to go to a specific index a la `IList<T>`, requires that the whole enumeration be 'enumerated', at least up to the specified index.

If you don't care about the evaluation of the entire `IEnumerable<T>`, then you can construct a `List<T>` taking the `IEnumerable<T>` as a constructor parameter, and then return the `List<T>` as an `IList<T>`